# Defining policy for all branches with known begin and end in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

TFS provides the possibility to define branch policies through its REST API. For each policy one can define a [Git ref scope](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/policy/settings#git-ref-scope) which works fine if the exact branch name or the beginning of a branch name is known.

Is there also a way to define a policy which automatically affects all branches where the begin and the end is known. For example `/refs/heads/foo/*/bar` should affect `/refs/heads/foo/foo/bar` and `/refs/heads/foo/bar/bar`, but not `/refs/heads/foo/foo/foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this. The matchkind only support "prefix" and "exact". I would recommend you to write a script to get a detailed list of refs which match "/refs/heads/foo/*/bar" and apply the policy to them programmly.

Comment: As branches can be added, this script must be re-run periodically or upon creation of new branches.